# Search files and when match is found, store it, then print out 4 lines above, 3 lines below

Tags: perl

I have a simple search script that takes user input and searches across directories & files and just lists the files it is found in. What I want to do is to be able to is when a match is found, grab 4 lines above it, and 3 lines below it and print it. So, lets say I have.

#### somefile.html

```
"a;lskdj a;sdkjfa;klsjdf a aa;ksjd a;kjaf ;;jk;kj asdfjjasdjjfajsd  jdjd
jdjajsdf<blah></blah> ok ok okasdfa stes test tes tes test test<br>

blah blah blah ok, I vouch for the sincerity of my post all day long.
Even though I can sometimes be a little crass.

I would only know the blue moon of pandora if I saw it. I heard tales of long ago 
times in which .. blah blah

<some html>whatever some number 76854</some html>

running thru files of grass etc.. ===> more info
whatever more "
```

and lets say I want to find "76854" it would print or store in an array so I can print all matches found in dirs/files.

```
*Match found:*

**I would only know the blue moon of pandora if I saw it. I heard tales of long ago 
times in which .. blah blah
<some html>whatever whatever</some html>
running thru files of grass etc.. ===> more info
whatever more**


**********************************
```

Something like that. So far I have and it is working by printing out files in which it finds a match:

```
if ($args->{'keyword'}){
    if($keyword =~ /^\d+$/){
    print "Your Results are as Follows:\n";
        find( sub
            {
                local $/;
                return if ($_ =~ /^\./);
                return unless ($_ =~ /\.html$/i);
                stat $File::Find::name;
                return if -d; #is the current file a director?
                return unless -r; # is the file readable?
                open(FILE, "< $File::Find::name") or return;
                my $string = <FILE>;
                close (FILE);
                print "$keyword\n";
                if(grep /$keyword/, $string){
                    push(@resultholder, $File::Find::name);
                }else{
                   return;
                }
             },'/app/docs/');
    print "Results: @resultholder\n";
    }else{
        print "\n\n ERROR\n";
        print "*************************************\n\n";
        print "Seems Your Entry was in the wrong format \n\n";
        print "*************************************\n\n";
    }
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to store at least 8 lines, and output those 8 lines when the 5th line matches your pattern. The `shift` operator, for removing an element from the front of an array, and the `push` operator, for adding an element to the end of a list, could be helpful here.

```
find( sub {
    ...  # but don't set $\

    open( FILE, '<', $File::Find::name) or return;
    my @buffer = () x 8;
    while (<FILE>) {
        shift @buffer;
        push @buffer, $_;
        if ($buffer[4] =~ /\Q$keyword\E/) {
            print "--- Found in $File::Find::name ---\n";
            print @buffer;
            # return?
        }
    }
    close FILE;

    # handle the case where the keyword is in the last ~4 lines of the file.
    while (@buffer > 5) {
        shift @buffer;
        if ($buffer[4] =~ /\Q$keyword\E/) {
            print "--- Found in $File::Find::name ---\n";
            print @buffer;
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: I am a perl newb and I have some questions if I may based on your code supplied. 
1. What does my buffer = () x 8; do? 
2. shift buffer; push buffer, $_; 
3. $buffer[4] ? <-- I understand the syntax here but why the 4?

Comment: 1. Creates a list with 8 empty elements. 2. [`shift`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#shift) removes first element from list. 3. [`push`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#push) adds element to the end of the list. 4. because `$buffer[4]` is the 5th element in the list. i.e., there are 4 elements before it and 3 elements after it.

Answer (score 3):

Is perl a prerequisite here? This is trivially easy with grep, you can tell it to print N number of lines before and after a match.

`grep <search-term> file.txt -B <# of lines before> -A <# of lines after>`

Please disregard if you really want to use perl, just throwing out an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Windows or Linux?

If you are on Linux your script is better to replace with:

```
grep -r -l 'search_string' path_to_search_directory
```

It will list you all files containing search_string. And to get 4 lines of context before and 3 lines after the line with match you need to run:

```
grep -r -B 4 -A 3 'search_string' path_to_search_directory
```

If for some reason you cannot or don't want to use grep, you need to improve your script.

First, with this construction you are reading only the first string from the file:

```
my $string = <FILE>;
```

Second, you'd better avoid reading all the file to the memory, because you can encounter several Gb file. And even reading one string to memory, because you can encounter realy large string. Replace it with sequential read to some small buffer.

And the last, to get 4 lines before and 3 lines after you need to perform reverse reading from the match found (seek to the position which is to buffer_size before the match, read that block and check if there is enough line breaks in it).

Comment: *"However it doesn't allow you to get 4 lines above and 3 below"*. You can do this by replacing `-4` with `-B 4 -A 3`